# TFS Build 2015, Gihub Enterprise and Pull Requests

Tags: github, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I'm trying to get TFS Build server 2015 to do continuous integration building for pull requests on our github enterprise server. I was able to get the triggers working and it was building all of the normal branches (/refs/heads/*), but I can't figure out how to get it to build new and updated pull requests. In the triggers I've tried pull/*, pull/*/head, origin/pr/*, origin/pr/*/head, refs/pull/*, refs/pull/*/head and just a plain *. * is what allowed it to build all branches.

This was pretty easy to do with our Team City build servers, but I can't figure this piece out. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2015, you can only select External Git repo for GitHub repo, and can only specify the branches where you want to trigger builds. No option to specify pull request.

[image]

[image]